# Turnstile with Mathcal: missing \endcsname inserted

Tags: errors, xparse, mathcal, turnstile

I was using the `turnstile` package and `xparse` package to use turnstile efficiently.
But from one point, I was keep getting an error message, and found that `\not{\sdtstile{\mathcal{S}}{}}` was the culprit.

The error message is

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.17 But $\not{\sdtstile{\mathcal{S}}{}}
                                        $ causes error, Missing \endcsname i...
```

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[openany,english]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[nonewtxmathopt]{newtxmath}  

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphicx}
\usepackage{turnstile}  
\usepackage{xparse}     
\usepackage{cancel}

\NewDocumentCommand{\st}{O{} O{}}{\text{\raisebox{0.1mm}{\scalebox{0.7}{$\ \,\sdtstile{#1}{#2}\,\,$}}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\nst}{O{} O{}}{\text{\raisebox{0.1mm}{\scalebox{0.7}{$\ \,\not{\sdtstile{#1}{#2}}\,\,$}}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\cst}{O{} O{}}{\text{\raisebox{0.1mm}{\scalebox{0.7}{$\ \,\cancel{\sdtstile{#1}{#2}}\,\,$}}}}

\begin{document}

\[\Sigma\st[\mathcal{S}]\alpha\quad \Sigma\nst[S]\alpha\quad \Sigma\cst[\mathcal{S}]\alpha\]
%But $\not{\sdtstile{\mathcal{S}}{}}$ causes error, Missing \endcsname inserted

\end{document}
```

[image]

So the problem is, `\sdtstile{\mathcal{S}}{}` and `\not{\sdtstile{S}{}}` works but `\not{\sdtstile{\mathcal{S}}{}}` doesn't work.
I learned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41161/negated-double-turnstile) that I can use the cancel package as in the example, but I just prefer the small 'not' sign.
Here, xparse seems not relevant, but I just wanted to mention that I wanted to use it as a macro.
And additionally, if someone has a better idea about the shape/margin of the turnstile in the macro, I'd be glad to get an advice!

Comment: I think the problems have their origin in the optional argument of `\sdtstile` -- it's not expandable. `\not\expandafter{\sdt....}` will work, but the slash is too much at the left part of the symbol

Comment: First time seeing the code '\expandafter'! But I think you're right; your code at least does not bring an error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `newtxmath` package redefines `\not`:

```
1738 %%% \not redefined:
1739 %%%    \not= becomes \ne
1740 %%%    \not< becomes \nless
1741 %%%    \not> becomes \ngtr
1742 %%%    if \notXXX is defined, \not\XXX becomes \notXXX;
1743 %%%    if \nXXX is defined, \not\XXX becomes \nXXX;
1744 %%%    otherwise, \not\XXX is done in the usual way.
1745 \DeclareMathSymbol{\n@tch@r}{\mathrel}{symbols}{54}
1746 
1747 \DeclareRobustCommand*{\not}[1]{%
1748    \ifx #1=\ne\else
1749    \ifx #1<\nless\else
1750    \ifx #1>\ngtr\else
1751    \n@t@@n{#1}\fi\fi\fi}
1752 
1753 \def\n@t@@n#1{%
1754   \begingroup \escapechar\m@ne\xdef\@gtempa{not\string#1}\endgroup%
1755   \expandafter\@ifundefined{\@gtempa}%
1756      {\not@n@{#1}}%
1757      {\@nameuse{\@gtempa}}}
1758 \def\not@n@#1{%
1759   \begingroup \escapechar\m@ne\xdef\@gtempa{n\string#1}\endgroup%
1760   \expandafter\@ifundefined{\@gtempa}%
1761      {\n@tch@r #1}%
1762      {\@nameuse{\@gtempa}}}
```

In particular, one can see that what comes after `\not` *must* be a single token. With your call of

```
\not{\sdtstile{\mathcal{S}}{}}
```

all conditionals are evaluated to false, because `\sdtstile` is not the same as `{`; so `\n@t@@n{#1}` is what remains; but at this point, TeX wants to do

```
\xdef\@gtempa{not\string\sdtstile{\mathcal{S}}{}}
```

and here's where the problem appears, because `\mathcal` cannot go in a replacement text subject to `\xdef`. What happens with the `\expandafter` proposed in comments? That the argument to `\not` is `\expandafter`, so the `\xdef` doesn't fail and makes the replacement text of `\@gtempa` into `notexpandafter`. Since `\notexpandafter` is undefined, the test on line 1760 follows the true branch and so the standard `\not` (now called \n@tch@r`) is used.

<sub>By the way, the `\expandafter` in lines 1755 and 1760 are completely useless.</sub>

The call of `\nst` in your example has no `\mathcal` and this is why it produces no error. If you try `\nst[\mathcal{S}]`, you'll see the same error.

Solution? Use a different definition:

```
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\nst}{O{} O{}}{%
  \text{\raisebox{0.1mm}{\scalebox{0.7}{$\ \,\n@tch@r\mathrel{\sdtstile{#1}{#2}}\,\,$}}}%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Of course this is specific for `newtxmath`; I see no “universal” workaround.

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm. I'll just wait a bit more to see other possible ways and opinions.

Comment: I am aware that my `\expandafter` - proposition could be no solution, I suspected the wrong evaluation already.

Answer (score 1):

This only works in display and textstyle (I could not get `\sdtstile` to scale with math style), but involves stacking the desired argument under the blank stile.

```
\documentclass[openany,english]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[nonewtxmathopt]{newtxmath}  

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphicx}
\usepackage{turnstile}  
\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand{\Nst}[1][]{\mathrel{\raisebox{0.1mm}{%
  \scalebox{0.7}{\stackunder[-3pt]{$\not{\sdtstile{}{}}$}{$\scriptstyle#1$}}}}}

\begin{document}
\[\Sigma\Nst[\mathcal{S}]\alpha\]
\end{document}
```

[image]