# How to make enough space around custom turnstiles?

Tags: math-operators, logic, turnstile

I use the package `turnstile`, but only to define my own macros because it doesn't define negated turnstiles and its turnstiles are too tall.

My non-negated turnstiles look fine to me (not as tall as `turnstile` defines them).
My negated turnstile looks ok *per se* too, but the spacing around it is all wrong.

Using the `cancel` package, as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41161/negated-double-turnstile), looks wrong to me because the bar crosses over any text under or over the horizontal bar(s), instead of crossing just the vertical stroke.

A MWE:

> simpleturnstile.sty

```
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{graphicx} % \reflectbox
\RequirePackage{mathtools} % \mathmakebox
\RequirePackage{turnstile} % turnstiles

\let\oldm@dels\models% standard |= symbol
\newlength{\m@delsheight}

% \models, \Models
\RenewDocumentCommand{\models}{O{{}} O{{}}}{% |- relation
\settoheight{\m@delsheight}{\f@size$\oldm@dels$}%
\ensuremath{%
  \mathrel{\resizebox{!}{\m@delsheight}{$\sststile{\mathrm{#1}}{\mathrm{#2}}$}}%
}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Models}{O{{}} O{{}}}{% |= relation
\settoheight{\m@delsheight}{\f@size$\oldm@dels$}%
\ensuremath{%
  \mathrel{\resizebox{!}{\m@delsheight}{$\sdtstile{\mathrm{#1}}{\mathrm{#2}}$}}%
}}
% \bimodels, \biModels
\newcommand{\bimodels}{\ensuremath{% -||- relation
  \mathrel{\reflectbox{\models}\,{\models}}%
}}
\newcommand{\biModels}{\ensuremath{% =||= relation
  \mathrel{\reflectbox{\Models}\,{\Models}}%
}}
% \notModels (negated \Models)
\newsavebox{\notModelsb@x}
\NewDocumentCommand{\notModels}{O{{}} O{{}}}{\sbox{\notModelsb@x}{\Models[#1][#2]}%
  \ensuremath{%
  \mathrel{\mathmakebox[\widthof{\notModelsb@x}][l]{\not\rlap{\usebox{\notModelsb@x}}}}%
}}
```

> simpleturnstile.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{simpleturnstile}

\begin{document}\Huge
$\{\alpha\} \notModels \beta$

$\{\alpha\} \notModels[CPC] \beta$

$\{\alpha\} \notModels[CPC][\Gamma] \beta$
\end{document}
```

Compiling `simpleturnstile.tex` yields:

[image]

How can I put proper spacing around the negated turnstile?

[EDIT] I managed to make the turnstiles scale, but I still have to fix the spacing around the negated one.

Comment: I think `\f@size` probably doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't set the font size, but just expands to the current font size in points (which is just a number), so it doesn't have much of an effect here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand why, but it seems that `\widthof` does not calculate correctly the width of the saved box `\notModelsb@x`, so it seems more appropriate to find another way to calculate the box's width. As @Circumscribe pointed out, the width of `\notModelsb@x` can be obtained with `\wd\notModelsb@x`. 
In your file `simpleturnstile.sty`, I replaced the `\notModels` section with

```
\newsavebox{\notModelsb@x}
\NewDocumentCommand{\notModels}{O{{}} O{{}}}{%
  \sbox{\notModelsb@x}{\Models[#1][#2]}%
  \ensuremath{%
    \mathrel{\mathmakebox[\wd\notModelsb@x][r]{\not\usebox{\notModelsb@x}}}%
}}
```

With the `simpleturnstile.sty` modified as above, the following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{simpleturnstile}

\begin{document}\Huge
\begin{tabular}{lll}
$\{\alpha\} \notModels \beta$ & $\{\alpha\} \notModels[CPC] \beta$ & $\{\alpha\} \notModels[CPC][\Gamma] \beta$ \\
$\{\alpha\} \Models \beta$    & $\{\alpha\} \Models[CPC] \beta$    & $\{\alpha\} \Models[CPC][\Gamma] \beta$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

compiles to 
[image]
So the spacing seems of the negated turnstiles is the same as that of the non negated turnstiles now.

Comment: N.B. the actual width of the contents of `\notModelsb@x` can be obtained with `\wd\notModelsb@x`.

Comment: @Circumscribe Thanks, I did not know that! It simplifies the code, so I edited my answer in consequence.